# How to get namespace?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid

Namespace is not detected in .cshtml page
I am using Telerik Grid. In Model, I created a class called Student.

```
namespace testRazorView.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
      ..
      ..
     }
}
```

In .cshtml page, I need to get the student class..so i used as following.

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<namespace>
```

namespace is not detected ie..testRazorView.Models.Student should be replaced in the namespace, but not detected. Provide solution for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can define @model also. Here is the article by Mr. Scot Guthrie himself - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/19/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor.aspx

Comment: Please don't use signatures in your posts.

Comment: @kashyapa, I used the model directive. Then also the same Issue is present.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is solved. I need to close the braces and afterwards, if I type, the namespace is detected. That is,

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<namespace>)
```

Now we have to type the namespace after closing the braces.
Thanks.